# if statement inside for loop in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to learn javascript and getting hung up on this. Basically trying to run the loop and only select the values if profile[i] equals another variable named pro.
Here is the code that selects everything.

```
      downloadUrl("phpsqlajax_genxml.php", function(data) {
      var xml = data.responseXML;
      var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
      var pro="<?php echo $inform['profile']; ?>";
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var profile = markers[i].getAttribute("profile");
  var date = markers[i].getAttribute("date");
  var catch1 = markers[i].getAttribute("catch1");
      var catch2 = markers[i].getAttribute("catch2");
      var catch3 = markers[i].getAttribute("catch3");


       var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("latit")),
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("longit")));
      var html = "<b>" + date + "</b> <br/>" + catch1 + "<br/>" + catch2 + "<br/>" + catch3;

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,

      });    
      bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
```

I tried adding

```
       if (profile['i'] = pro)
       {
```

after

```
      var profile = markers[i].getAttribute("profile");
```

but it still loops through the whole thing.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning instead of comparing. Use `==` instead.

```
var profile = markers[i].getAttribute("profile");
if (profile['i'] == pro)
{
    var date = markers[i].getAttribute("date");
    var catch1 = markers[i].getAttribute("catch1");
}
```

Comment: Or `===` if you don't want to compare equivalent types.

Comment: Thanks that was it. I also had to change profile['i'] to just profile.